# Submit form with a Form Key and via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, forms

All,
I have the following class so to check to see if the form that is created via HTML is valid and also prevents the form from submitting twice if someone does a ctrl+F5 etc. Here is the class that does that:

```
<?php
class Form_Key
{

protected $oldKey;

public function __construct()
{

    // Ensure we have an available session
    if ( NULL == session_id() )
    {
        session_start();
    }

    // Grab our former key for validation
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['form_key'] ) )
    {
        $this->oldKey = $_SESSION['form_key'];
    }

    // Assign the new key
    $_SESSION['form_key'] = md5( uniqid( mt_rand(), TRUE ) );

}

public function isValid()
{
    return 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
        && isset( $_POST['form_key'] )
        && '' != trim( $_POST['form_key'] )
        && '' != trim( $this->oldKey )
        && $_POST['form_key'] === $this->oldKey;
}

public function getKey()
{
    return $_SESSION['form_key'];
}

public function getOldKey()
{
    return $this->oldKey;
}

public function render()
{
    return '<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="' . $_SESSION['form_key'] . '" />';
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->render();
}

}  
?>
```

Then I have a form that looks something like this:

```
require "form_key.php";
$form_key = new Form_Key;
<form action="about.php" method="post" name="create_memory" id="create_memory">
<input type="text" value="" id="lamecaptcha" name="lamecaptcha" />
<input type="text" value="" id="person_name" name="person_name" />
<?php echo $form_key; ?>
</form>
```

On the validation side (save_memory.php) I do something like this:

```
require "form_key.php";
$form_key = new Form_Key;
if(isset($_POST) && $form_key->isValid()){
    echo "It is ok to submit";
}else{
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
```

All of this works great if I don't submit the form via ajax but if I submit the form via AJAX it always gives me the something went wrong error. Here is how I'm submitting the form via AJAX:

```
person_name = $("input#person_name").val();
memory = $("input#memory").val();
form_key = $("input#form_key").val();
var html_memory = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "save_memory.php",
data: "person_name=" + person_name + "&memory=" + memory + "&form_key=" + form_key,
async: false
}).responseText;

alert(html_memory);
```

Any ideas why this is the case and how can I get this to work submitting my form via AJAX? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery selector for key input is invalid. You have to put an ID of form_key to that, like so:

```
 return '<input id="form_key" type="hidden" name="form_key" value="' . $_SESSION['form_key'] . '" />';
```

[EDIT]

Also you have to call a function that generates the input:

```
<?php echo $form_key->render(); ?>
```

Comment: @Kristian good catch on the id thing. however, the output is rendered as it is. first code body, magic method __toString is called when the object is printed, which happens in second code block, echo $form_key;